# How would i create a bot command that kicks everyone in the server (discord.js-commando)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, commando

i want to create a command that kicks everyone in the guild that it is executed in; how would i do this

ive been searching for a while today and tried before too but i cant find any answers

thanks in advance

Comment: Why you want to do it?

Comment: the idea is that id add a randomiser to thanos snap the server but i didnt add that to make the question a little bit more vague.

edit: the owner of said server (my friend) is the one who told me to do it

Answer (score 2):

This is something that is really easy to do if you read the discord.js documentation.

Now, I am not going to tell you exactly how because there are too many people asking for this type of stuff to "troll" servers AKA destroy the communities. If you are not doing this to ruin a server, I am sure you will be willing to put in time and effort to help your friend out. If so, take a look at the discord.js documentation for about 30 minutes (or even less) to learn how to do it. Here is a link to the docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Sorry if this isn't your intention but I don't want to help the evil accidentally :/

Comment: ive read for a bit and the idea is that it gets a list of all users and kicks user[i] (with a 50% chance randomiser).

of course its a small scale project and im either in servers with friends or big servers that i dont moderate

copied from another comment of mine:

the idea is that id add a randomiser to thanos snap the server but i didnt add that to make the question a little bit more vague. edit: the owner of said server (my friend) is the one who told me to do it